# A simplicial circle as the link of a vertex in a polygon with side identifications.

Tags: general-topology

[image: Link is clearly a simplicial circle?]

The bold lines which make the link of $v$ aren't even closed polygons how can they be simplicial circles- if it means when you put all three together- if you label the vertices of the links 1,2,3,4 won't they all overlap to give one of copy of the original 3 edged shape which is not a closed polygon?

Comment: Each pair of opposite edges on the hexagon is identified, as shown by the arrows.

Comment: Oh wait I realise a vertex added in the inside of the hexagon is not identified with any of the other extra vertices put in - so you need to label the extra vertices differently- so say instead you label those links as: 1,2,3,4  and 1,2,5,6 and 1,2,7,8

Comment: @Theophile brilliant I get it- ignore my above comment-